# Husband's UK visa rejected after 10 years of successful applications, made one mistake applying for EEA permit just before this visit visa application

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals

Here is the refusal letter. We don't know what to do now and how to apply again, as we applied with the same format we have used for a decade.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Also, which parts of the refusal reasons do you find confusing?

Comment: When my parents are sponsoring my husband completely,  why does his balance master,  not only that but we have a healthy account with transactions, just the end balance is not considerable

Comment: Was he refused entry on 3 May 2018 as the letter says? That would seem to contradict what you said about ten years of successful applications.

Comment: 3rd may we applied for an EEA Family permit,  not understanding it completely and regrettably wrote that in our application as last time we had applied was 8 years ago when he was given a 5 year visa,  this new option popped up when we were starting his visa application and we thought we were elligible.  Found out later that is not for British spouses.

Comment: We have property here and he has been employed at the same place of work for 12 years,  so how else can we show strong ties here?

Comment: @Arwa Pisavadi Applying for an EEA family permit may have made it appear that your husband has immigrant intentions, and the Visit visa refusal also highlights some other deficiencies/inconsistencies in the application. Now with two consecutive refusals the situation is complicated and you may we’ll need the advice of a lawyer with immigration expertise.

Comment: @Traveller I think that might be an answer.

Comment: @ArwaPisavadi: You should edit the question to include the information on the EEA family permit, important information (like that) should never just be in a comment.

Comment: Looks like you sabotaged your own application with the previous displaying of an intent to immigrate. The additional things the ECO officer hit you with are probably bonus, the real thing is the intent to immigrate. Maybe a solicitor can help.

Answer (score 6):

Applying for an EEA family permit may have given the impression that your husband has immigrant intentions, and the subsequent Visit visa refusal highlights some other deficiencies/inconsistencies in the application. With two consecutive refusals the situation has become complicated and you may well need the advice of a lawyer with immigration expertise before attempting a further application, or a document check such as those offered for example by https://www.freemovement.org.uk/immigration-application-checking-service/